# Hit URL in local VM machine via AJAX/REST

Tags: json, ajax, rest, server, virtual-machine

I am new to API methodology so sorry for asking such silly question which it may be.I am running Windows 10 on my machine and have setup a `Ubuntu VM` on Oracle `VM VirtualBox`. I want to hit the `url` in `AJAX/REST` way to get the `JSON`.I am able to get that `JSON` data in browser when I am hitting the `url` within `VM` environment. How can I accomplish the same via desktop?

I am running a separate server utility on `VM` which accepts the following `url`

```
localhost:8998/sessions
```

and it provides me data in form of `JSON`.

I have written the following code with help of W3Schools.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "192.168.56.780:8998/sessions", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This should return json file in output in the same way as that when I run in browser in VM environment but no output is there on it in specified section.

**UPDATE:**

I have made changes in "Network" settings of VM making Adapter 2 as below and started the image:
[image]

Now I am able to `putty` it through new IP address `192.168.56.780` assigned automatically by it.Will this solve the above problem.

Comment: "not working as expected." is not an error message or problem statement. What exactly is going wrong? What errors or unexpected behaviour do you get?

Comment: P.S. Despite your vague description, I think this could be a problem: "I am running a separate server utility on VM which accepts the following url: localhost:8998/sessions"...`localhost` only works when the browser is on the same machine as the webserver. It always maps to the same machine that you use it from. So it's fine when both are on the VM. But if you want to do it from the desktop (physical machine) to a webserver on the VM, then you simply need to substitute localhost with the IP address of the VM. Otherwise it tries to access a webserver on your physical machine.

Comment: P.P.S. I see in the actual code you used 127.0.0.1. 127.0.0.1 is also an alias for localhost, which is used on all machines. It's not unique to your VM. You need to find the actual IP address or hostname of the VM's network interface. Presumably you know it, because you must be connecting to the VM in order to deploy your code onto it etc.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for mentioning the same. I have updated further on my findings.Please look above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. "Nothing is happening" isn't an adequate description either. Look at your browser's developer tools (the console, and the network area) and note any error messages or unexpected results. You can actually view the ajax request (assuming it's actually being triggered) as it happens and look inside it to see what was sent and received and what the response code was. This is the kind of debugging information which would be useful to share. Also, do you get a different result if you run in a browser inside the VM, than if you run in a browser from the desktop?

Comment: And did you change the IP address as I suggested?

Comment: @ADyson I made changes as above.Will it suffice.

Comment: If the webserver is listening on that IP address then hopefully yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: Can you tell me the way of doing this thing.Should I check with PUTTY or how?

Comment: yeah you can log in via putty, or remote desktop if you enabled it. But you didn't say what webserver you're using. Apache? nginx? You can check the documentation for your product which will tell you how to configure it. You can also google how, in Linux, to check what IP addresses are active on your VM and maybe you can try each one. The likelihood is the webserver is listening on the original IP (it looks, from the question, like you've created 2nd network adapter for some reason, it's not clear to me what was wrong with the first one)

Comment: It is using Jetty Server as checked in code and documentation of https://livy.incubator.apache.org/

Comment: ok well I don't know anything about that but you can check the documentation. But also just try your code first - if it already works then you haven't got any research to do.

Comment: I'll repeat my previous comment: _I don't know anything about that but you can check the documentation._ But, before you do that, test your code now to see if it works. If it works, you don't need to check anything.